# adb server stutters ubuntu desktop

Tags: adb, linux

My environment is:
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (xubuntu to be more specific),
NVidia driver 470.103.01,
Android SDK 33

When I start adb server by running some adb commands, the UI, mouse and other things starts to lag and stutter, only terminal keeps responsive. You can see the type of lags I'm talking about on the video. Note that even when the cursor is lagging the terminal still works smoothly. The task manager doesn't seem to register any spikes neither on CPU nor on memory usage. Do you have any idea of how to debug or fix this issue? Probably you faced something similar?

Thanks in advance

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YSdN9WtYQU

Edit:
If I use MX Master 2S bluetooth mouse which connects directly to the bluetooth integrated into the motherboard, I see the effect described above. But if I connect cheap bluetooth mouse via its' bluetooth dongle, I don't see the stutter effects, everything runs smoothly. Looks like adb somehow interfere with builtin bluetooth device

Comment: Have you connected an Android device via USB? If yes try what happens if you remove it. What other USB devices are connected?

Comment: Thanks, but no android devices connected. Even if I connect one and make adb recognize it, nothing changes, it still acts just like on the video

Comment: Reader's note: also posted on Ubuntu.SE: https://askubuntu.com/q/1450546/331791

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I ended up connecting the mouse using a USB dongle instead of built-in Bluetooth. Not a solution to the initial problem, but anyway, this is a note for somebody who faces similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your adb server as root with these commands in the terminal window:

```
adb kill-server        # Get rid of any running server
sudo adb start-server  # Start a new one running as root
```

If that does not start the stutter, try running your other commands and see if they stutter. In general, ADB works *much* better on Linux if the server is running as root.

OK, that isn't the problem, which seems to be something to do with the motherboard bluetooth controller. Check if there are driver updates for that, and for the USB controller?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately sudo doesn't make any differense, the same stutter, no changes

Comment: I've added more info to the question, looks like this is somehow related to the bluetooth device

Comment: Added another suggestion.